How to get coordinate of motioned widget in certain point?
I want to simulate smart speed cameras.
I placed the photo of the car and set it in motion.
I want the speed to be recorded when it reaches a certain point (camera location).
The problem is that I can't get the position of the car when it reaches the camera.
I am a beginner in Python and Tkinter.
from tkinter import *
import time
import random
w = 800
h = 600

window = Tk()
window.title("Drawing and Move")
window.geometry('800x600')
window.resizable(width=False , height=False)

canvas = Canvas(window, width=w, height=h)
canvas.place(x=10 , y=10)
canvas1 = Canvas(window, width=w, height=h)
canvas1.place(x=10 , y=60)
canvas2 = Canvas(window, width=w, height=h)
canvas2.place(x=10 , y=110)


car_img = PhotoImage(file="images.gif")
car = canvas.create_image(10,10,anchor=NW, image=car_img)
car1 = canvas1.create_image(10,10,anchor=NW, image=car_img)
car2 = canvas2.create_image(10,10,anchor=NW, image=car_img)

cam_img = PhotoImage(file="cctv.gif")
camera = Label(window,image=cam_img)
camera.place(x= 400,y=200)



while True:

    canvas.move(car, random.randrange(1,10),0)
    canvas1.move(car1,random.randrange(1,10),0)
    canvas2.move(car2,random.randrange(1,10),0)

    window.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

window.mainloop()





Try using print("") on your car, and set it to print at the moment you want it to.
Also, you declared two variables; w and h, which has 600 and 800 as their values. However you have used the geometry method and typed it in manually, whereas you could have typed in window.geometry(f"{w}x{h}"). Just pointing that out.
I might be wrong, as I am also a beginner in Tkinter, but using regular Python command lines could do the trick.
